# how to use multiple generator expressions to init single list

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to init a single list using multiple generator expressions. The following code shows what I've ended up with, but I'm not sure it's the "right" way. How are you suppose to use multiple expressions?

```
z = [ *(x for x in range(4)), *(y for y in range(5))]
```

note: in my real code the expressions are more complicated than range so please don't try to get clever about the actual values above. I do need multiple generator expressions

Comment: What makes you think it's not the right way? Is there a *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: What jon said. But if you don't actually need the list, or want to be compatible with older versions of Python, take a look at `itertools.chain`

Comment: I'm new to python. still looking for the python way to do things (too much of what I write looks like C code). At the moment I don't care about older versions of python. the * with the ()s made me feel like I was forcing something that could be done cleaner.

Comment: If you want a list, you might as well add two list comprehensions (to be more backwards compatible)

Comment: what's the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

One opinion:

```
>>> z = []
>>> g1 = (x for x in range(4))
>>> g2 = (y for y in range(5))
>>> z.extend(g1)
>>> z.extend(g2)
>>> z
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: I did try something like: z = [ x for x in range(4)]+[y for y in range(5)]